# "Read Permission" Permission Quirks

Tags: windows-server-2008, permissions

Server 2003 R2 w/sp2

Having an issue with users not being able to read & execute once the "read permissions" permission is removed.

Comment: Sorry, sounds like you're removing the read permission, then the user can't read the file!

Comment: Uh, yeah.  How would they be able to read if you're removing the permission?

Comment: No, in the special permissions you have the "Read Permissions" permission. I am removing this and am unable to open the file. The read permission is never removed. At this point I wonder if "Read Permissions" is referring to a group of permissions rather than a permission itself. I am under the impressions that the "Read Permissions" permission allows/disallows a user to view the permissions of a file. Please correct me if I'm wrong though.

Comment: Ahhhh, ok.  I'm with you now...  Sorry, my bad!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the ACL on a file as being a permission slip. Before you can read the file, you (or your system) needs to check the permission slip to see if you have access. If you deny access to the permission slip, you can never check it, so the system denies you access to the file.

Comment: Yep, thats kinda what I was thinking but looking for verification. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a reason that "read permissions" is granted for every basic permission setting. I believe this is, "working as designed."

Comment: This is direct from Microsoft.

Read Permissions
The Read Permissions permission allows or denies the user from reading permissions about the file or folder, such as Full Control, Read, and Write.

Why do I need to have this checked in order to read/open a file? What if I don't want the user to be able to see who has what permissions?